# Send an email when uploaded file shares same field name using Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to figure out a way to have an email send out to me using SharePoint workflow every time a file with same document number is uploaded.

This is what I have, any help is appreciated.

```
Step 1
If Current Item:Document Number equals Current List:Document Number
    Email Pucho
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call REST api(eg:`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('title')/items?$filter=documentnumber eq 'value'`) to check is any document item with same document number.

To call REST api from workflow, check below sample.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only thing is that my boss wants me to work with out-of-the-box features to prevent customizations from breaking with future SharePoint upgrades. Is there an option to only work with the workflow without having to mess with the code?